# Why actions take much more time after window transformation of a dataframe

Tags: python, pyspark

I have a dataframe with several millions of rows. It always took about a minute to make some actions over it, for example, print.
However, after I introduced window transformation of a dataframe, actions take up to 10 minutes and sometimes crash a cluster or exit with an error:

```py
'org.apache.spark.SparkException: Could not execute broadcast in 300 secs.'
```

I am interested in high level explanation why it happens. Is window transformation so heavy? What is general advise for optimization?

Comment: show code please

Comment: It depends on the transformation you make, it may be not parallelizable.